# Mocha Chai or JEST or BOTH?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Sorry this might be off topic question but I'll ask it anyway.

I am a newbie and I was thinking about test driven development.

Can you use jest for testing node/express?
Or do you need to use mocha for node/express and jest separately for react?

trying to learn MERN stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jest, it is a replacement for Mocha.

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible* to use Jest for node / express development. However, you will probably find the development process more painless when using mocha and chai (I tried using jest on the backend once, but we felt that we were fighting with the tooling too much for the frontend / backend consistency to be useful, and we ultimately switched everything over to mocha in the end).

It's quite easy to get started...

Just install the dependencies:

```
npm i --save-dev mocha chai
```

add add a script in your `pakage.json` file to run the tests:

```
mocha **/*.test.js
```

Good luck!